# Failed Converting base64 between Android and Java-Wildfly 8

Tags: java, android, base64

I have problem between converting base64.

Android: sender:

```
android.graphics.Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

String base64String = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("address/WebService-1.0/base64/do");

try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("base64String", base64String));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    System.out.println("OK");

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

And Java - Wildfly 8: receiver

```
@Path("/base64")
@Stateless
public class Base64Services {
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Base64Services.class);

@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/do")
public Response execute(String base64String) {
    byte[] decodedByte = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(base64String);

    Path destinationFile = Paths.get("dirToFiles\\tmpFiles", "myImage.jpg");
    try {
        Files.write(destinationFile, decodedByte);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.info("OK");
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

}

Bitmap is ok because it displays correctly in Android app.

On the other hand, when I try to open the image file, it receives "We can not open the file"

Ask for help where I make a mistake in converting between systems